# Retrieve the current version of a given post

Tags: database, postgresql

I version posts for a project of mine. Database currently looks like this:

```
posts
  bigint id
  datetime created_at

post_versions
    bigint id
    int major_version
    int minor_version
    bigint post_id
    string title
    text contents
```

I want to be able to always get the current version of a given post. The current version is defined as:

> The post version with largest major and minor version for a given post

I'm thinking that a database view containing "current versions" would be a good choice but I'm not sure where to start. Every time a new version is created, the database view would update to reference the latest version for the given post.

Using the view I would then be able to easily query the current version for a given post.

Any ideas where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the split of major & minor version is going to make your query logic quite complex. Both your major & minor versions are 32 bit signed integers. Hence, I'd create a function that combines these into a single 64 bit signed integer that can be used as a single value to compare. For example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION version(int, int) RETURNS bigint AS
'SELECT ($1::bigint << 32) + $2'
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```

This will make the view logic much easier. You would then just create a view that returns the max of the version for each post. For example:

```
CREATE VIEW post_latest_versions AS
SELECT *
FROM post_versions p1
WHERE version(major_version,minor_version)=(
    SELECT MAX(version(p2.major_version,p2.minor_version)) 
    FROM post_versions p2 WHERE p2.post_id=p1.post_id
)
```

You could then use `post_latest_versions` as required. You should consider if you should make this a [materialised view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html) for performance.

There are many alternative approaches you could use if you control the persistence layer. For example, you could be storing the ID of the latest post version for each post ID in another table.

Comment: The major and minor version could be represented in any way, as long as I can still differentiate them. Would there be an easier solution if I would represent them as a string, e.g., "1.0"?

Comment: No, representing as you have is fine. You want to use an ordinal type so comparison is easy. What's wrong with the approach suggested above?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. I was just wondering since you wrote "Having the split of major & minor version is going to make your query logic quite complex.". Thought you might have had a different take on it if you could decide the structure more freely.

Comment: You could store the version as a single 64 bit integer and this would negate the need for the function. You would then perhaps create a couple of utility functions to extract the major & minor versions, either as integers or as a single string. It's really a matter of preference. All I meant was that it's easier to compare a single value than try to and compare two integers, particularly with sub queries. The extra complication that this logic would impose is probably why creating a view seemed difficult.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Appreciate it.